# Mutating data in Alpine JS

Tags: alpine.js

I am trying to achieve something that seems trivial.

```html
    <main x-data='x'>
       <p x-text='foo'>
    </main>
```

The `foo` needs to be changed by some external event (callback from a library etc.)

This

```js
    window.x = {
       foo: 'bar',
       setFoo: foo => this.foo = foo
    }
    
    // late, after `alpine:init`
    
    window.x.foo = 'boo' // doesn't work
    window.x.setFoo('boo')  // doesn't work
```

The same goes for the `$store`.
I can try and declare `Alpine.data('x')`, but then there is no (documented) way to call a setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `x` is now an Alpine.js component, so you have to use the *Alpine.js way* to mutate the reactive data. First, instead of `p-text`, you have to use `x-text`:

```
<main x-data='x'>
   <p x-text='foo'>
</main>
```

And to mutate data, you can access the reactive properties in [`$data`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/data) object:

```
x.$data.foo = '42'
```

For the store you can use the global [`Alpine.store()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store#accessing%20stores) method:

```
// Create number1 property in $store:
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.store('number1', '0')
})

// Set number1 to 42 externally:
Alpine.store('number1', 42)
```

Comment: `p-text` was a typo of course. What is `extcomp` in your answer?

Comment: Sorry, `extcomp` is a 'typo', it is `x` in your case, the name of the Alpine.js component. I named it `extcomp` in my test environment.